# my url pattern throwing an error

Tags: python, django

my url pattern is `www.example.com/[any digit or number]` say `www.eaxmple.com/slug`

my urls.py is:

```
 url(r'^(?P<[a-z0-9>+)/$', mymethod),
```

But is saying:- `bad character in group name`

another query is that i want to process the `slug` coming with the url. Based on that value i will render different template. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know python, so can't say what the url function does, but your regex should probably look like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<someName>[a-z0-9]+)/$', mymethod)
```

This will capture the the [a-z0-9] Group of characters under the name "someName".

BTW: What about upper case characters?

Comment: [any digit or number] doesn't indicate that he wants any letters in there :-)